# Expand certain macro invocation

Tags: macros, elixir

I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35204849/969451), but there is no explanation about expansion of certain macro invocations. For example, how do I see what this invocation expands to?

```rb
defmodule Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  test "always pass", do: assert true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much follow the approach from the question you linked:

```
defmodule Test do
  use ExUnit.Case

  # (other tests here)  

  ast = quote do
    test "always pass", do: assert true
  end
  expanded = Macro.expand(ast, __ENV__)

  IO.puts "Original:"
  # IO.puts inspect(ast, pretty: true)
  IO.puts ast |> Macro.to_string
  IO.puts ""
  IO.puts "Expanded:"
  # IO.puts inspect(expanded, pretty: true)
  IO.puts expanded |> Macro.to_string
end
```

If you run the tests now with `mix test`, you'll see the expanded version of the `test` macro:

```
Original:
test("always pass") do
  assert(true)
end

Expanded:
(
  var = {:_, [], ExUnit.Case}
  contents = {:__block__, [], [{:assert, [context: CrawlieTest, import: ExUnit.Assertions], [true]}, :ok]}
  message = "always pass"
  (
    name = ExUnit.Case.register_test(__ENV__, :test, message, [])
    def(unquote(name)(unquote(var))) do
      unquote(contents)
    end
  )
)
```

You can uncomment the `IO.puts inspect(_, pretty: true)` lines to see how the original and the expanded version look in the [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html) representation.

Comment: What I've missed in the approach from the linked question is that `if/2` is macros too :)